# Using "Putting up" in day to day conversation

Tags: speech

How to use "Where do you put up?".
Is it the right replacement for "Where are you staying?".

Answer (score 2):

I have heard the phrase "where are you putting up?" but only, if I remember rightly, in an old film.

This [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where+are+you+putting+up%2Cwhere+are+you+staying&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhere%20are%20you%20putting%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhere%20are%20you%20staying%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase has cropped up in written English from time to time, but almost never compared to "where are you staying?" although it did enjoy a brief period of popularity in the very early 20th Century.

Personally I would avoid the phrase entirely and stick with "where are you staying" in order to maximize the chances of being understood.

Answer (score 1):

For ‘put up’, the Oxford Dictionary gives ‘’Take or provide with accommodation (friends put me up for the night)’.
In British-English ‘putting up’ in the sense of *providing* overnight accommodation is in current use.
The ‘*taking* accommodation’ usage is more dated. I can imagine some hearty fellow in a 1920s novel declaring that he was ‘putting up at the village pub’, but it would carry a connotation of enduring basic accommodation for the sake of convenience. 
What the dictionary definition omits is the sense of the accommodation being temporary, which is always understood.
There may be sections of society who still use the term, but in my experience most people would now use ‘stay’ to describe a temporary residence.
 In Scotland ‘stay’ will also be used in reference to permanent accommodation.
Is there a reason you need a replacement for the perfectly acceptable ‘where are you staying?’?

Answer (score 0):

You are

```
   being put up
```

That is, someone else is putting you up by providing the accommodation. You might ask

```
   Please could you put me up for the night?
```

So you, the guest, do not "put up", rather you are "being put up" by the host.

*Staying* has a more general application, covering both visiting as a guest and also paying a hotel for a room, possibly for an extended period.

*Being put up* very much implies a temporary, or grace-and-favour arrangement.